# Noticeable alerts in Outlook for Mac (2011)

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, calendar

I don't often get invited to meetings, but when I do I usually miss them due to the very inconspicuous nature of Outlook's meeting reminders.

Typically, it quietly pops up a window under everything else, doesn't "bounce" and the only way for me to get a reminder is to notice that blue reminder icon on the dock in the midst of 50 or so other icons. Often I'm in a VM so I may not even see the dock.

**Is there any way to get a reminder I have some hope of actually *seeing?***

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Growl](http://growl.info/)? It is a very handy application with very configurable alerts; I use this to alert me for all my various email accounts, etc..

Comment: How would the OP use growl? If you expand on what it will do based on what settings or commands you give it, your answer would be more clear and more valuable to the OP as well as future visitors. You might even want to include step-by-step instructions for setting something up, or screenshots.